# Почему при работе с Vue белый экран?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        showFAQ: false,
        activeIndex: null,
        faqItems: [
          { question: 'Вопрос 1', answer: 'Ответ на вопрос 1' },
          { question: 'Вопрос 2', answer: 'Ответ на вопрос 2' },
          { question: 'Вопрос 3', answer: 'Ответ на вопрос 3' },
        ],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleAnswer(index) {
        this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex === index ? null : index
      },
    },
  }
</script>
<template>
  <button class="btn">test</button>
  <div id="faq" v-if="showFAQ">
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in faqItems"
      :key="index"
      class="faq-item"
      @click="toggleAnswer(index)"
      :class="{ active: activeIndex === index }"
    >
      {{ item.question }}
      <div v-if="activeIndex === index">{{ item.answer }}</div>
    </div>
    FAQ
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>

<style>
  .faq-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .faq-item.active {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Почему на экране отображается только кнопка, а остальное нет? подскажите как это можно исправить?

Comment: Наверное вот поэтому: `showFAQ: false,` -> `v-if="showFAQ"`

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Все получилось! Здоровья, долгих лет жизни и всех благ!

Answer (score 0):

Считаю, что вопрос необходимо снабдить ответом.

У вас в шаблоне (`template`) используется условный рендеринг (`v-if="showFAQ"`). Изначально у `showFAQ` значение `false` и в коде оно никак не изменяется, поэтому ничего кроме кнопки не рендерится.